# Which version of dcmtk is compatible with gcc version 4.8.2?

Tags: linux, dcmtk

I am trying to install dcmtk 3.6.0 on my linux system gcc version 4.8.2. But i get an error "Resize which is part of ofoset.h is not defined in this scope". Upon reading, i realized that this happens due to mismatch in the versions of the dcmtk and gcc version. But i am not able to find the right one for my complier.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc version 4.8.2 was not available when DCMTK 3.6.0 was released (see INSTALL file). So, you should download the latest development snapshot of the DCMTK: http://blog.jriesmeier.com/2013/11/how-to-get-the-current-development-version-of-the-dcmtk/